# OpenCV: parabola detection using Hough Transform

Tags: image, opencv, hough-transform

I want to detect parabola(s) of type : y^2 = 4a*x in an image[size: 512 X 512]. I prepared an accumulator array, acc[size: 512 X 512 X 512]. I prepared a MATRIX corresponding to that image. I used hough-transform. This is how I did it:

```
for x = 1 to 512
  for y= 1 to 512
   if image_matrix(x,y)> 245//almost white value, so probable to be in parabola
   {
     for x1= 1 to 512
       for y1= 1 to 512
       {
           calculate 'a' from (y-y1)^2 = 4*a*(x-x1).
           increment acc(i,j,k) by 1
       }
   }

if acc(i,j,k) has a maximum value.
{
   x1=i, y1=j,a =k
}
```

I faced following problems:

1) acc[512][512][512] takes large memory. It needs huge computation.How can I decrease array size and thus minimize computation?
2) Not always max valued-entry of acc(i,j,k) give intended output. Sometimes second or third maximum, and even 10'th maximum value give the intended output. I need approx. value of 'a', 'x1','y1'(not exact value).

Please help me. Is there any wrong in my concept?

Comment: You could post a link to an image example

Answer (score 3):

What i'm going to say may only partly answer your question, but it should work.

If you want to find these type of parabolas

```
 y^2 = 4a*x
```

Then they are parametrized by only one parameter which is 'a'. Therefore, i don't really understand why you use a accumulator of 3 dimensions.

For sure, if you want to find a parabola with a more general equation like :

```
y = ax^2 + bx + c
```

or in the y direction by replacing x by y, you will need a 3-dimension accumulator like in your example.

I think in your case the problem could be solved easily, saying you only need one accumulator (as you have only one parameter to accumulate : a)

That's what i would suggest :

```
  for every point (x,y) of your image (x=0 exclusive) {
      calculate (a = y^2 / 4x ) 
      add + 1 in the corresponding 'a' cell of your accumulator 
      (eg: a = index of a simple table)
  }

  for all the cells of your accumulator {
      if (cell[idx] > a certain threshold) there is a certain parabola with a = idx
  }
```

I hope it can help you,
[This is as well an interesting thing to look at :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502726/hough-transform-for-finding-curve-segments)
Julien,